# Merge 2 columns on separate sheets into one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have 2 lists on two separate sheets and I am trying to combine them into a third sheet. These lists auto-populate based on user input, so the number of rows within the list can vary. So once it detects nothing in the first column of sheet one, it starts populating the list on sheet 3 with the columns in sheet 2, like this

Sheet 1

```
Make    Model     License Plate
Ford    Escape    UVC345
Honda   Civic     KD2YR9
```

Sheet 2

```
Make    Model    License Plate 
Dodge   Charger  34TRLS2
VW      Passat   V70YTR
```

Sheet 3

```
Make    Model    License Plate
Ford    Escape   UVC345
Honda   Civic    KD2YR9
Dodge   Charger  34TRLS2
VW      Passat   V70YTR
```

Update:

The problem I'm running into when I use VBA to copy and paste, is that it is pasting and identifying the formulas that are used to autopopulate the initial list on sheet 1. Because it is pasting the formulas, it is not correctly identifying where the last cell is on sheet 3.

```
Sub Copy_Alternatives()

Worksheets("CNA eTool Alternatives").Range("A:A").Copy
Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Range("A:A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("CNA eTool Alternatives").Range("B:B").Copy
Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Range("B:B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("CNA eTool Alternatives").Range("C:C").Copy
Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Range("C:C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub

Sub Copy_Paste_Range()

Dim lNewRow As Long
Dim lDataRow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Activate

lNewRow = Worksheets("CNA eTool Addit. Alternatives").Cells(Worksheets("CNA eTool Addit. Alternatives").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

lDataRow = Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Cells(Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lDataRow = lDataRow + 1

Worksheets("CNA eTool Addit. Alternatives").Range("H2:J" & lNewRow).Copy
Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Range("A" & lDataRow).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to write a macro that does that for you. Depending a bit on how you want to automate the process, but the code could just loop through the used rows in sheet 1 and  2, and copy the content to sheet 3. And then either update the list on changes, or rewrite the list.

Comment: The problem I'm running into when I use VBA to copy and paste, is that it is pasting the formulas that are used to autopopulate the initial list on sheet 1. Because it is pasting the formulas, it is not correctly identifying where the last cell is on sheet 3.

Comment: Just to clarify before I get home and try, you want to copy the value retuned by the cell, not the formula in the cell, correct?

Comment: yes, I updated the initial question with the code. When I paste regularly it is pasting the formulas, and when I paste as values it returns a 0. I need it to paste just as a blank cell.

Comment: Try skiping the pasteboard entirely and use `Worksheets("Repair Replacement Recom").Range("A:C").value = Worksheets("CNA eTool Alternatives").Range("A:C").value`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with worksheet functions.

Lets say your first Sheet is `Sheet1` and the second is `Extra1`

Put the following formula on your merged sheet on A2, then copy paste to the other cells:

`=IF(ROW()>COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)+COUNTA(Extra1!A:A)-1,"",INDIRECT(IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),"Sheet1!","Extra1!")&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),1,"")&ROW()-IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),0,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1)))`

How this works:

1. Checks if the current line is higher than the number of lines on the first sheet + the second sheet minus one(Because both have headers);
2. If the current line is greater, show empty. Else, goes to next step;
3. Prepares an `INDIRECT`. If the current line is lower than the lines on the first sheet, gets the first sheet name. Otherwise it gets the second sheet name;
4. It uses the `SUBSTITUTE + ADDRESS` trick to return the current letter of the column. It is good because then it uses the same formula on all fields, and accepts even when the column becomes AA
5. Finally, it gets the current line if the current line is lower than the number of items on the first sheet, otherwise it gets the current line MINUS the count of lines of the first sheet, minus one, to return the starting line of sheet two.

I know it is kinda overwhelming and harder to read, but formulas sometimes are better than VBA.

Edit: Welp, I got an epiphany and got a working VBA version

```
Sub merge()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'First sheet to get merged
Set ws2 = Sheets("Extra1") 'Second sheet to get merged
Set ws3 = Sheets("Merged") 'Name of the sheet you want results
Dim lr As Long 'To return the number of the last row
Dim arrayone As Variant
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arrayone = Range(ws1.Cells(2, 1), ws1.Cells(lr, 3)).Value 'From Row 2 onwards, considering it has headers
Dim arr2 As Variant
lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arr2 = Range(ws2.Cells(2, 1), ws2.Cells(lr, 3)).Value 'From Row 2 onwards, considering it has headers
Dim arr3 As Variant
ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arrayone, 1) + UBound(arr2, 1), 1 To 3)
For i = 1 To UBound(arr3, 1)
    For j = 1 To 3
        If i <= UBound(arrayone, 1) Then
            arr3(i, j) = arrayone(i, j)
        Else
            arr3(i, j) = arr2(i - UBound(arrayone, 1), j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Range(ws3.Cells(2, 1), ws3.Cells(UBound(arr3) + 1, 3)).Value = arr3
End Sub
```